# Prevent changing subitems belonging to wrong items

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application with events. Each event contains items. Events table is below:

```
+----+-------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | category_id | event_name | event_description | event_startdate     | event_closedate           | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |           1 | Event 1    | Event 1           | 2016-05-02 00:00:00 | 2016-06-30 00:00:00       | 2016-07-07 15:59:03 | 2016-07-08 12:26:07 |
|  2 |           1 | Event 2    | Event 2           | 2016-06-02 00:00:00 | 2016-07-30 00:00:00       | 2016-07-07 15:59:03 | 2016-07-08 12:26:22 |
|  3 |           2 | Event 3    | Event 3           | 2016-07-02 00:00:00 | 2016-08-19 00:00:00       | 2016-07-07 15:59:03 | 2016-07-08 12:27:04 |
|  4 |           2 | Event 4    | Event 4           | 2016-09-01 00:00:00 | 2016-10-30 00:00:00       | 2016-07-07 15:59:03 | 2016-07-07 15:59:03 |
+----+-------------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

and each event contains a number of items for which the table is as follows:

```
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| id | event_id   | item_name | item_description      |
+----+------------+-----------+-----------------------+
|  1 |          1 | Item 1    | Item 1 - description  |
|  2 |          1 | Item 2    | Item 2 - description  |
|  3 |          2 | Item 3    | Item 3 - description  |
|  4 |          2 | Item 4    | Item 4 - description  |
|  5 |          3 | Item 5    | Item 5 - description  |
```

I'm displaying the current events on the homepage. I want to ensure that the items belong to the event. So the following should work:

```
http://localhost:5000/event/2/item/3
http://localhost:5000/event/3/item/5
```

And the following should not work

```
http://localhost:5000/event/2/item/1
http://localhost:5000/event/3/item/4
```

I'm solving this currently through adding some logic in my controller (for the route /event/{event}/item/{item}. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
$now = Carbon::now();

$event = Event::where('event_startdate', '<=', $now)
            ->where('event_closedate', '>=', $now)
            ->findOrFail($event->id);

$item = Item::where('event_id', '=', $event->id)
        ->findOrFail($item->id);


return view('guest/items/detail', ['item' => $item]);
```

If the event id is belonging to an event in the past or in the future it will give a 'not found' view. Similar, if the item does not belong to an event, it will give a 'not found' view.

While this work, I feel this is not a best practice and there must be more optimal methods to achieve this?

Relevant routes are as follows:

```
Route::get('event/{event}/item/{item}', ['as' => 'item_details', 'uses' => 'Guest\ItemsController@showItemDetail' ]);
```

Comment: What `$lot` refers to ??

Comment: Sorry, that was a leftover of something I tried earlier on and forgot to change. I've corrected it in the original question.

Comment: Can you also add your routing in the question?

Comment: Guess you should to a 404 redirect in cases where the item does not belong to the specified event.

Comment: I suggest to add a method in the Event model that do the check if an event has the given item return it else throw an exception or return 404.

Comment: @Kjell: the example is working and am being redirected to a 404 page (because the findOrFail). Question is more related to how I can find a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Sidenote, I don't think either of the `->where()` clauses have much of an effect on your results if you're searching for a specific `$event->id` or `$item->id`. Personally I'd query for existence of the item, check that the `event_id` of that item's event (`$item->event->event_id` or `$item->event_id`) matches the given `$event_id` variable from the URL parameters and then check the dates of the event. Throw errors/redirects where required.

Comment: @TimLewis The where clause is there to check for current events only. If I would not have them, it would execpt also older events or future events. So the id is checked to ensure it's a current event.

Comment: @TimLewis I now understand your comment better. See the below answer I posted. Believe this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback received, I came up with the following:

```
public function showItemDetail(Event $event, Item $item)
    {
        $event = Event::findOrFail($event->id);

        if ($event->id != $item->event_id) {
            abort(403);
        }

        return view('guest/item/detail',  ['item' => $item]);

    }
```

Believe this is better than my original approach.

Comment: Not quite... This is a bizarre approach. You're passing an `Event $event`, then trying to find `Event::findOrFailt($event->id);`. That's redundant. Not to mention you'd have to have an `Event` object in your URL as a parameter, which I doubt you can do. I'll write a quick answer for ya, clear up my comment.

Comment: Understanding your first comment about the redundancy, the second point is just route model binding where you can pass the event object in the URL.

Comment: Right, but I wasn't aware that you can pass a whole object via a URL parameter; pretty sweet if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I was a little incorrect in my comment about the `->where()` clauses; they would work to filter down the `Event` to only return if within a specific date-range. Here's my approach:

If you're using Laravel's relationships, you can easily find the `Event` attached to this `Item` and verify that it is the correct one. In the same check, you can check for existence of both `$item` and `$item->event`, integrity of the `$eventId` URL parameter and that the `$event` is within a certain time period:

```
public function showItemDetail($eventId, $itemId){

    $now = Carbon::now();

    $item = Item::with(["event" => function($query) use($now){ 
        $query->where('event_startdate', '<=', $now)->where('event_closedate', '>=', $now);
    }])->where("id", "=", $itemId)->first();

    // Check that the Event's ID matches that in the URL
    if(!$item){
        abort(403); // No Item found.
    } else if(!$item->event){
        abort(403); // No Event found.
    } else if($item->event->id != $eventId) {
        abort(403); // Mismatched EventID
    }
}
```

The above is just an example of the logic, it would likely be simpler to create a `$valid = true;` flag, set it to `false` if any of those conditions are met, and only return an `abort(403)` if `if($valid == false)` equates to `true`. Also `findOrFail()` is an acceptable approach, I only use `->where("id", "=", $whatever)->first()` for the extra control.